# Generating increasingly longer lists from a single list

Tags: list-manipulation, algorithm

I start with an array such as `{{1,1},{0,1},{-1,1}}`. **(1)**

I want to create an array from this which replaces each array inside the array with 3 new arrays, one prepended with 1, one prepended with 0 and one prepended with -1. For example, applying this to the above array would give:

`{{1,1,1},{0,1,1},{-1,1,1},{1,0,1},{0,0,1},{-1,0,1},{1,-1,1},{0,-1,1},{-1,-1,1}}`     **(2)**

I need to find an efficient method to apply this multiple times to an array (i.e. the same algorithm would then be applied to **(2)** yielding a list containing 27 lists and so on).

I have tried using For loops but cannot get them to work and I suspect they would be very slow.

Ideally I would also like to be able to specify how many times to apply this algorithm.

Comment: In the above text, the (1) and (2) are meant as labels for equations, rather than something to do with the actual problem.

Comment: Please hold on with an accept (a day or two), let's do not discourage others. Better answers may appear :) I'm glad it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(Flatten /@ Reverse /@ Tuples[{#, {-1, 0, 1}}]) & @ {{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}}
```

> ```
> {{-1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1},
>  {-1, -1, 1}, {0, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}}
> ```

```
Nest[ (Flatten /@ Reverse /@ Tuples[{#, {-1, 0, 1}}]) & , 
      {{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}},
      2]
```

> ```
> {{-1, -1, 1, 1}, {0, -1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1, 1}, {-1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 
>  1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 
> 1}, {-1, -1, 0, 1}, {0, -1, 0, 1}, {1, -1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 0, 1}, {0,
>  0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 
> 1}, {-1, -1, -1, 1}, {0, -1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, -1, 
> 1}, {0, 0, -1, 1}, {1, 0, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1, 1}, {0, 1, -1, 1}, {1,
> 1, -1, 1}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very literal way of doing precisely what you described:

```
f[arr_] := Sequence[Prepend[arr, 1], Prepend[arr, 0], Prepend[arr, -1]]

f /@ {{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}}
```

You can think of `Sequence[a,b,c]` as representing `a,b,c` without any other expression surrounding them.

Answer (score 0):

Just for variety:

```
f[s_] := ({#, Sequence @@ s} & /@ Range[-1, 1]);
g[lst_] := Join @@ (f /@ lst);
```

So,

```
test = {{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}};
g[test]
```

gives:

```
(*{{-1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 
  1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {0, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}}*)
```

and can be nested:

```
Nest[g, test, 2]
```

gives:

```
(*{{-1, -1, 1, 1}, {0, -1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1, 1}, {-1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 
  1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 
  1}, {-1, -1, 0, 1}, {0, -1, 0, 1}, {1, -1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 0, 1}, {0,
   0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 
  1}, {-1, -1, -1, 1}, {0, -1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, -1, 
  1}, {0, 0, -1, 1}, {1, 0, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1, 1}, {0, 1, -1, 1}, {1,
   1, -1, 1}}*)
```